# Changing culture only changing the language of model items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I have implemented the culture in my Asp.net application. But what I want is to change the language of the entire page but it's changing only model items language.

CultureHelper.cs

```
 public class CultureHelper
 {
        protected HttpSessionState session;

        public CultureHelper(HttpSessionState httpSessionState)
        {
            session = httpSessionState;
        }
        public static int CurrentCulture
        {
            get
            {
                switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name)
                {
                    case "en": return 0;
                    case "hi-IN": return 1;
                    default: return 0;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
                }
                else if(value==1)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN");
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                }
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
            }
        }
    }
```

BaseController.cs

```
protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
            int culture = 0;
            if (this.Session == null || this.Session["CurrentCulture"] == null)
            {

                int.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"], out culture);
                this.Session["CurrentCulture"] = culture;
            }
            else
            {
                culture = (int)this.Session["CurrentCulture"];
            }
            // calling CultureHelper class properties for setting  
            CultureHelper.CurrentCulture = culture;

            base.ExecuteCore();
        }

        protected override bool DisableAsyncSupport
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
```

My model class

```
 [Display(Name="Name",ResourceType =typeof(Resource))]
```

Language only changing for the model class properties. But I want to change the language for static/nonmodel properties too. Like I want to change button text too. I have added all contents in the resource file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So your buttons are already using the resource file similar to this? `<button type="submit">@Resources.Submit</button>`

Comment: this is what I have written `<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />`

Comment: How can I reference Resource file in the view ?

Comment: `@using MyProject.Resources`

Comment: Thanks but if I write this `@using MyProject.Resources` this will only print same value on all Languages. This value must be changed on Changing culture

Comment: You have to add multiple Resource files for the different cultures (`Resources.en.resx`, `Resources.hi-IN.resx` etc.). The framework will resolve which resource file to use based on the set `CurrentCulture`. `Resources.resx` will be used as fallback if no culture specific file can be found.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Please add it to answer so that I can mark it as `correct`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a resource file for every culture you want to support, e.g.

```
Resources.en.resx 
Resources.hi-IN.resx
```

The framework will resolve which file to use based on the set `CurrentCulture`.
`Resources.resx` (without culture name) will be used as fallback if no culture specific file can be found.

Use the resource file to retrieve your translated strings, e.g. in your View.cshtml:

```
@using MyProject.Resources

<button type="submit">
    @Resources.Submit @* this retrieves the translation for the key "Submit" *@
</button>
```